# Which way to unscrew the behind part of the v pipe?

Tags: bathroom, pipe, sink, clog

I am trying to remove the pipe bellow my bathroom sink to clean it (clogged).
I made loose the facing screw but I can't the behind one. The one in the red square.
I am not sure which way is the correct way to turn so I am not trying too much in order to avoid any damage.
How can I unloose it in an easy and safe way?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can often determine the whether the threading is right or left handed by looking closely at the first thread between the edge of the fitting. Your picture is not clear enough to tell this from the photo but this shows where to look.

[image]

That said it is a pretty good guess that you would turn as shown below to remove. This is the conventional direction for the most often used right hand threads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Monkey wrench. But on its own will cause damage to the nickel.

[image]

To avoid damage use a tough rubber lining in between the contact parts. 
The wrench works by getting the gap to a close enough size as the part you want to un/tighten, when you apply force to the handle, it starts to compress the gap, exerting grip torque while unscrewing in the axis your are turning in. When you release pressure on the bar it lets go. So the more you push the bar the more torque in-between the gap, so be careful not to over do it.

Basically a plumbers must have tool and a very versatile one too!